# Change ID(int) to UUID

Tags: sql-server

I have a large database with many relationships. The database can be rebuilt and a migration script for an already existing data base

For security reasons, the URL should not show the `ID(int)` only `UUID`

Is there any good advice for such a situation?

- converting all `IDs` to `UUID`(if so how to do it efficiently?)
- can I create an additional column in each UUID table and use it at the address? (if so how to do it efficiently?)
- other suggestions?

Comment: There were similar questions, but without any interesting help in this matter

Answer (score 4):

> can I create an additional column in each UUID table and use it at the address?

You can add an alternate key using a UUID like this:

```
alter table SomeTable add uuid uniqueidentifier unique not null default newsequentialid()
```

Which will add minimal overhead, and provide efficient single-row lookups.

Comment: So add an additional column from the UUID and rebuild the queries so that they can be used in the UUID address instead of INT?

Comment: Yes, but do not forget to add an index on the UUID column and set the FILLFACTOR a little bit lower than 100 % (e.g. 95 - 98 %, depending how much records are inserted per time period (between your index optimize runs)  compared to the total number of existing rows.

Comment: Fillfactor is only helpful when using NEWID() and random GUID generation (and 75% is better there), and the UNIQUE constraint creates a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

> For security reasons, the URL should not show the ID(int) only UUID

Ok, that makes sense.

> converting all IDs to UUID(if so how to do it efficiently?)

There is no way *convert*. Converting would be `id(int) = new_id`. This is against the foundation of the question. You either have to

1. generate new UUIDs to replace the IDs and update the data.
2. compromise on your foundation.

> [...] other suggestions?

If you only need security through obscurity and not **real** security, the easy solution there is to use HashIDS. There is a [port of it to SQL Server,](https://hashids.org/tsql/)

```
insert into my_table(id) values(dbo.encode1(1));
insert into my_table(id) values(dbo.encode2(1, 2));
```

Essentially, it's not `id(x)`, it's `id(salt,x)`. It has the benefit of,

- Not making joins slow
- Not making indexes large
- Being able to calculate it in runtime on encode/decode
- Not having to update your ids and rewrite your schema
- Being able to conceal the function from users, **so long as the salt itself is kept secret and the hashing remains safe from attack**

Comment: UUID in the URL must be used. Can you say something more about adding an extra column from UUID? How to use it later, etc.?

Comment: With this method, you don't need an extra column. Though if you insist you could make it a `COMPUTED COLUMN` https://github.com/waynebloss/hashids-tsql https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but something like this script?
Works with PostgreSQL (Maybe, no guarantee)

Data stcuture

```yaml
users:
  - id
  - name
posts:
  - id
  - user_id
  - title
```

Example using knex.js query builder

```js
const createKnex = require('knex')
const { v4 } = require('uuid')

const knex = createKnex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
})

async function migrate() {
  await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
    await trx.raw("SET session_replication_role = 'replica';")

    const users = await trx('users')

    for (const user of users) {
      const uuid = v4()
      const userId = user.id
      await trx.raw('update users set id = :uuid where id = :userId',
        { uuid, userId },
      )
      await trx.raw(
        'update users set user_id = :uuid where user_id = :userId',
        { uuid, userId },
      )
    }

    await trx.raw("SET session_replication_role = 'origin';")
  })
}

migrate()
```

Comment: "Works with PostgreSQL" unfortunately this question is tagged [tag:sql-server] ...

Comment: Oh sorry. I've missed the tag. The essential is the same though.